# Tab bar items con scroll

Tags: swift, scroll, swift4

Estoy realizando una app para iphone que tiene un tab bar controller con 4 elementos, el problema es que los titulos son largos y hay muy poco espacio.

Hay alguna forma de hacer que los tabs tengan scroll para que aparezca el ultim elemento haya que hacer scroll en la barra de los tabs?

Comment: Tendrías que hacer una vista custom, haciendo la navegación de nuevo. Lo recomendable es ajustar el diseño, los Tabs debiesen usarse con iconos representativos.

Answer (score 1):

Una buena alternativa es usar un collectionView y habilitar la paginacion. Por ejemplo si tienes 5 elementos y con el tamaño de ideal de cada tab (o celda en este caso)solo caben 4, asigna el ancho de cada celda asi:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
     return CGSize(width: screenWidth/4, height: 100)
}
```

El elemto restante sera visible cuando hagas el scroll